All local devices refuse to connect to localhosted servers on new windows installs
I recently setup a new system to replace my previous server (running Windows 11 Pro 23H2) which has been running fine for well over a year.
The new system just got a fresh install of Windows 11 Pro, and Ive updated it to 24H2.
Everything currently works fine. I can run all my software and programs without issue, I can access any and all internet services with the computer without issue. I can even SFTP between the new server and local devices
However, any applications hosting services to my local IP on any port are inaccessible to every LAN device connected to wifi.
EX:
Jellyin - localhost:8096 (Accesssible via 198.162.50.243:8096 on a particular device) is unrecognized by any other device on the network (Phones, Macs, other Windows PCs)
As a control, I booted up my old server (which had since been wiped and also had a fresh install of windows 11 setup, but with no dev utilities or settings changed. Just a generic install of Win 11 Pro 24H2) - I gave it the same jellyfin test (and other services which I could access through localhost). This time accessible via 198.162.50.125:8096... Same results as the main server. Nothing could see this server hosted at this port.
What I've tried so far:

I gave windows firewall specific rules giving jellyfin (or whatever service I was testing at the time) full access for both incoming and outgoing rules on any port with any protocol.
I completely disabled windows defender firewall to see if it was still causing issues.
I attempted fully wiping network settings within windows to no avail.
I tried checking the manual settings and permissions for public and private networks for the particular service, but also changed the identifier of the network between public and private.
Tried changing DNS or hosting rules for the specific applications in case there was something blocking local connections
I tried going onto the router settings and validating that it could see all the devices hosting these local servers, and it saw them fine.
I used netstat on the devices to verify that the ports were alive and listening - Which they were.
Given the services full administrator priviledges within windows and access to any part of the computer without limitation. I wanted to verify there was absolutely nothing blocking it from being accessed / exposing itself to the LAN.
While I didnt think it would affect local network connections, I also enabled UPnP on the router. (I do not specialize with networking and am inexperienced with debugging it, so I apologize in advance if this was an obvious error)
Tried pinging each device alone to see if they could even recognize the local IP Address, and they fire "Timed out" messages. It appears they cant even see eachother
Made sure that the windows settings for allowing the PC to Discover traffic and to BE discoverable were all set to allow traffic.

Im out of ideas here, I've already sought support with individuals from the specific service's support groups, who also had no idea what my issue was, and Ive researched countless similar situations online to no avail.
This issue has occured on both windows 11 servers and Im seeing no obvious difference between my old setup and the new one. Ive touched no settings on my router (beyond UPnP) and as far as Im aware Ive configured nothing special on my previous servers for this to work. I've never experienced any issues with local devices refusing to connect to the IP:PORT of another device on the network, assuming the server is online and properly configured.
